# Python looping through dictionary: TypeError: unpack non-sequence

Tags: python, dictionary

```
sub = {} 
for a, b in sub:                   #<--- error occurs here
   for s in b:
       #do blah. I was told a b is a list
```

and it gives me `TypeError: unpack non-sequence`

What is this mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
for a, b in sub.iteritems():
    # Do Something.
```

Doing

```
for a, b in sub:
    #...
```

tries to assign `(a, b)` to a key in `sub` which may not be a sequence.

Comment: Use [`iteritems()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems) where possible :)

Comment: yes. grrr the tutorial i was looking at was wrong then...

Comment: is there any difference between the iteritems() and items()?

Comment: `iteritems()` returns an iterator, which Python version are you on?

Comment: @woozyking: I don't know what version he is on. `items()` returns an iterator in Python 3.x.

Comment: @ealeon: Then use `iteritems()`.